# searchTwitter for all tweets from a specified location

Tags: r, twitter

I want to generate stats for twitter by location, e.g. number of tweets per city by date. If I use the searchTwitter() function in the twitteR package I can add a geocode location and a since time paramater but I must also  specify a search string. Is there any way I can just search for tweets by geocode location and date with no search string?
What I am currently using is something like this

```
location <- paste0(lat,",", lon,",", radius)
searchterm <- "twitter"
date <- Sys.Date()
searchTwitter(searchterm, n=1500, geocode=location, since=as.character(date))
```

But I want to search for all tweets from my specified location not just ones containing the string "twitter". Is this possible? I want to see growth in twitter around smaller towns/cities around the country so each individual location specific search I would not expect to return a lot of results.

Comment: Is it possible to include a search term as " "? Will this return all tweets. It does return something but its hard to tell if its returns all tweets. Any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search API does not provide the level of access you want. It will only return the 'most relevant' tweets and this can [be based on personalisation](https://blog.twitter.com/2011/engineering-behind-twitter%E2%80%99s-new-search-experience). In addition tweets returned could be set from within the area you specify OR the user's profile lists that geo-coded as home.

If you need an exhaustive list of tweets which match your query you should look at instead services like [DataSift](http://datasift.com). These have access to all public tweets you can use their query language to request a stream of GeoFencing.

Answer (score 1):

Make your searchterm `NULL`:

```
searchTwitter('', n=1500, geocode=location, since=as.character(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem for my research. I was trying to get tweets only in certain municipalities in the Netherlands. I used another map to intersect the tweets. In first instance I only gathered the tweets that are georeferenced and in the Netherlands. Then I used a map of the municipalities of the Netherlands to intersect this SpatialPointDataFrame with the municipal borders. The results are stunning, I have a map that exactly shows all urban areas covered with points and the forests are almost clear of points. But I can only use the tweets that have a location attached to it. Took me a while to figure this out, hope it helps other people!

```
tweets <- dbReadTable(con,name="tweetned0302")
coords <- cbind(tweets$longitude, tweets$latitude)
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, tweets, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat     +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
tweets_transformed <- spTransform(spdf, CRS = CRS(proj4string(region_of_interest)))
tweets_in_roi <- gIntersects(tweets_transformed, region_of_interest, byid=TRUE, prepared=TRUE)
Municipality1 <- tweets_transformed[tweets_in_roi[1,],]
```